# CSS multiple different off/out transitions

Tags: css, hover, transition

Imagine a white box. The box can turn either Blue or Red depending on circumstances. I want the box to fade back from Blue to white slowly, but it should fade back fast from the Red to the white color.  How do I achieve that, since the box-transition seems to apply to both fades when it goes back to white.

I have done a lot of searching and reading on CSS transitions recently. I now know how to make an element transition differently between two states, e.g. quickly from state A to B, and then slowly back from state B to A.

However, is there a convenient way to write CSS so that an element always transitions the same way from A to B, but in **multiple** ways back from B to A. For example say that I want to go back from :hover to base-state in multiple different ways, maybe fast the first time, then slower the next time, and then even slower the third time I hover off an element.

And as always: Is it possible to do this with only CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

actually u need to set transition on hover state of you want back immediately.

```
div.a{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background: blue;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
div.a:hover{
background: red;
transition: all 1s;
}
```

here is the fiddle for understanding https://jsfiddle.net/waf745hf/

Comment: That's a great example of a transition that goes one or both ways. How  would you write the CSS so that the duration on the "back-phase" would be alternating between  different values. In your example, it transitions back during 1-second but could you make it transition back for 2 seconds the next time you hover over it and remove the mouse, maybe by utilising a different class?

Comment: yes you can add toggle class and apply styles on it. looks at this fiddle now https://jsfiddle.net/waf745hf/6/ green color is going back slow to 2seconds. you can remove green color background your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the second reply! I've gone through the code now a couple of times and it probably is the best way to do it. However, it can be pretty difficult to handle the toggling when there are a lot of elements that needs to be toggled on and of based on special cues. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the solution depends on scenarios. you asked for simple solution so i tried to provide it. i will be happy to help you if you share actual problem of your project.  :)